# The checkmark for "positive question record" clips a bit

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Just noticed this earlier on my Mac, but the checkmark when you click a badge description (i.e. [badge:socratic]) clips a bit.

Here's an image for a better description.

OS X El Capitan, 10.11.4
Safari Version 9.1 (11601.5.17.1)

Also confirmed on my Windows box:

Windows 10 Enterprise
Google Chrome Version 49.0.2623.87 m

[image: Bug image]

Comment: We should consider migrating this to [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com), as I confirmed this behavior on at least one other Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. Yes, this is global issue related to whole network, not only CR. I'm working on this right now.

Comment: Thanks @Paweł! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. Thanks for reporting.